# How to visualize called narrowPeak files in UCSC Genome browser?

Tags: chip-seq, bed, ucsc

I have this file:

[image]
and I get this error

I googled and found this solution but it still doesn't work and I get this error
[image]
Error File 'GSM2797523_FOXA2_IDR0.02_narrowPeak_try.bed' - line 1 of custom input: variable needs to start with letter '"Peak name=""Somite narrowPeak""" '

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Found a way!!!
opened it with text editor and not exel as before and added the line:
track type=narrowPeak name="Somite narrowPeak"

Comment: Could you please forward the first error and  provide some context to your study for example explaining the data behind each column. Sometimes minimal context questions are answered, but usuaully they are ignored.. The title doesn't make grammatic sense  'visualize called narrowPeak files in UCSC Genome browser?'

Comment: This is the error
  Error File 'GSM2797523_FOXA2_IDR0.02_narrowPeak.bed' - Error line 1 of custom track: thickStart out of range (chromStart to chromEnd, or 0 if no CDS)

Answer (score 2):

Headers should not contain tabs:

```
track type=narrowPeak name="Somite narrowPeak" description="Somite narrowPeak"
```

Ensure that you have NO tabs on that line.

Comment: I made sure and now I get this error:

  Error File 'GSM2797523_FOXA2_IDR0.02_narrowPeak_try.bed' - Unrecognized format type=narrow line 2 of custom track

Comment: The type is narrowPeak, not narrow

Comment: track type=narrowPeak Peak name="Somite narrowPeak" description="Somite narrowPeak"         
 Changed it and still get this error: 
Error File 'GSM2797523_FOXA2_IDR0.02_narrowPeak.bed' - Unrecognized format line 1 of file: "track type=narrowPeak Peak name=""Somite narrowPeak"" description=""Somite narrowPeak""" (note: chrom names are case sensitive, e.g.: correct: 'chr1', incorrect: 'Chr1', incorrect: '1')

Comment: Where is this extra "Peak" coming from?!? Just use EXACTLY what I wrote with ABSOLUTELY NO CHANGES. If you get an error message then it is because you did NOT follow these instructions.